# WCF Action attribute.change results in Client being unable to see function when service reference is updated

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a WCF service to receive data from a client. We have no control over the client, in-fact I don't think our customer has the source. A previous developer has a note that the OperationContract[Action = ..] attribute must be specified.

I am also creating a test client to send some mock data to check that I process the data correctly. I use the base address (http://localhost:9000/SKUChange/) listed from the app.config of my service to add a service reference to the test client.

```
      <services>
        <service name="ME_BAT_ClassLib.MessageReceiverService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TNTLS_MessageProcessorSoap">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/SKUChange/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

If I leave the [OperationContract] with default attributes.

```
    [OperationContract]
    string ProductInformationMessage(string parTNTProductInformation);
```

When I update the service reference within my test client I can see my function ProductInformationMessage.

[image: Default Attributes]

If however I change the [OperationContract] Action attribute to the value required in the notes my test service (`[OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost/webservices/ProductInformationMessage", ReplyAction = "*")]`) no longer see the function.

[image: Action Attribute specified]

I have tried altering the address when going to "Add service Reference to no luck. I am sure I a missing something very obverse!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ReplyAction should not be '*' or wcf will not publish metadata about the operation. Normally, the replyAction should be Action + "Response", so please change it to http://localhost/webservices/ProductInformationMessageResponse, then you should see the method

Comment: I have started on this road of realisation. I discovered that if removed the Response attribute that it worked. The next step was to do as you say make response = Action. Its good to have further confirmation. I found out that the other developer was using VS2017 and I was on 2015,  I don't know if that made a difference. I don't think he made a test client for his system just kept altering things until the real client was able to send data successfully